# Joomla 3.4.1 Bootstrap .2.3.2 - Dropdown Login as Menu item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, authentication, module, joomla3.0

I have a problem with my self created Joomla 3.4.1 Template.

I am using the included Bootstrap 2.3.2 version, and have and nav-bar with dropdown menu items. That works fine.

Now I like do add an additionale menu-item where a dropdown-menu shows the Login-Windows.

I found a lot of extensions (modules) for that part. But all the modules have the same problem. They need a position. So it is not correctly integrated in the joomla-menu and it is not correctly responsive.

Does anybody has an idea, how I can fix that issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found the solution:

```
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">Login/Logout</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="Login" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```